# Rails: Is the flash object part of the session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, controller, session-cookies

According to the docs:

> The flash is a special part of the session ...

Which makes me think that if `reset_session` is called then that would explain why my flash message doesn't persist over a `redirect_to`.

But the research I've done seems to suggest that calling `reset_session` should not clear the flash.

Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you call `reset_session` before `redirect_to`, so your solution is *perhaps* to integrate the flash message into the `redirect_to` call

```
def good_bye
  reset_session
  redirect_to good_bye_path, notice: 'Good bye'
end
```

Comment: This answer gave me some insight to the solution I actually used, so I accepted it. I did have to store the message from the flash in a temporary variable and then reload it into the `redirect_to` variable. I'm still unclear why calling `reset_session` clears the flash. My research has turned up contradictions as to whether the flash is a part of the session or a separate, yet related, entity. I'm too lazy to deep dive the rails code and get a definitive answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, and what I came up with is that the flash helper is initialized with a version of the session, and after the reset_session I assume that a new session object is created that the flash helper is not aware of.